# how to replace null values by using row_number condition in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, row-number, isnull

I have a database in which I need to consider two partitions data: area_code and dates. Then I have the price for each area and for each date. When I have null values(and then missing price) for each area and date, I want replace those missing with the most recent (or last) not null values. So, I want to get the last not null value only if it is between the previous 7 days. I added a row_number from the first null value shown. In this way, if the price is missing when row_number is lower than 7 then it replace the row with the most recent value shown, otherwise it is null.

The code is the one shown below. How can I solve this?
I use ONLY SQL SERVER 2008

```
SELECT first_var, second_var, third_var, 
                ISNULL(third_var, 
                 (SELECT TOP 1 third_var FROM #table
                        WHERE first_var=t.first_var
                                and second_var<t.second_var
                                AND third_var IS NOT NULL
                                and rownumber<=7        -----this is the main constraint                     
                        ORDER BY first_var, second_var desc)  
                        ) as fourth_var,
        fourth_var
FROM   #table t
order by first_var asc, second_var
```

I have this

```
x1, x2, x3, x4
01, oct 1, null, 9
01, oct 2, 1.4, null
o1, oct 3, null, 8
o1, oct 4, null, 7
o1, oct 5, 1.5, null 
o1, oct 6, null, 6
o1, oct 7, null, 5
o1, oct 8, 1.4, null
o1, oct 9, null, 4
o1, oct 10, 1.3, null
o1, oct 11, null, 3
o1, oct 12, 1.2, null
o1, oct 13, null, 2
o1, oct 14, null,1
```

I want this

```
x1, x2, x3, x4
01, oct 1, null, 9
01, oct 2, 1.4, null
o1, oct 3, null, 8
o1, oct 4, null, 7    --- stop here here
o1, oct 5, 1.5, null 
o1, oct 6, **1.5**, 6  --change
o1, oct 7, **1.5**, 5  --change
o1, oct 8, 1.4, null
o1, oct 9, **1.3**, 4  --change
o1, oct 10, 1.3, null
o1, oct 11, **1.3**, 3  --change
o1, oct 12, 1.2, null
o1, oct 13, **1.2**, 2  --change
o1, oct 14, **1.2**,1  --change
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, edit your question and put the query in the question as *text*, not an image.

Comment: edited. please can you check again?

Comment: Replace `and rownumber<=7` with `DATEADD( DAY, -7, t.second_var ) >= second_var`